# WebSphere MQ: Message keeps toggling between input queue and backout queue

Tags: ibm-mq, weblogic-10.x

The logic flow is like this

1. A message is sent to an input queue
2. A ProcessorMDB's onMessage() is invoked. Within this method several operations/validations are done
3. In case of a poison message(msg that application code cannot handle) a RuntimeException is thrown.
4. This should rollback the transaction. We are seeing evidence in the log file.
5. There is a backout threshold defined with a backout queue name
6. once threshold is reached, the message is sent to backout queue
7. But immediately it starts going back and forth between the input queue and backout queue.
8. We are using MQMON tool to observe this weird behavior. It continues for ever almost even after the app server(where MDB is running) is shutdown.
9. We are using Weblogic 10.3.1 and WebSphere MQ 6.02

Any help will be much appreciated, looks like we are running out of ideas.

Comment: Perhaps you can post some code that handles the rollback of the transaction? When viewing the message that is seen bouncing back and forth can you verify that it is the exact same message with the exact same header properties (ie. redelivery count and such)?  Also, are you using your own backout queue for poison messages or are you using a system dlq?

Comment: @gwhitake: No, we have defined a "ErrorQ" for the backout queue. There is no code to handle the rollback transaction, we are using MDBs with CMT. As I stated, we simply throw a runtime exception if an error is encountered in processing. We are unable to verify the message headers since it keeps jumping between queues and we simply cannot catch hold of it. ie by the time we refresh or want to view the details the message would have gone to the input Q. It's a weird behavior and that is why reaching out

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a syncpoint issue.  If the QMgr were to issue a COMMIT when a message is requeued inside of a unit of work it would affect all messages under syncpoint inside of that thread.  This would cause serious problems if an application had performed several PUT or GET calls prior to hitting the poison message.  Rather than issue a `COMMIT` outside of the program's control, the QMgr just leaves the message on the backout queue inside the unit of work and waits for the program to issue the `COMMIT`.  This can lead to some unexpected behavior such as what you are seeing where a message lands back on the input queue.

If another message is in the queue behind the "bad" one and it is processed successfully by *the same thread*, everything works out perfectly.  The app issues a `COMMIT` on the new message and this also affects the poison message on the Backout Queue.  However if the thread were to exit uncleanly (without an explicit disconnect or `COMMIT`) then the transaction is rolled back and the poison message is returned to the input queue.

The usual way of dealing with this is that the next good message (or batch of messages if transactions are batched) in the input queue will force the COMMIT.  However in some cases where the owning thread gets no new work (perhaps it was performing a `GET` by Correlation ID) there is nothing to push the bad message through.  In these cases, it is important to make sure that the application issues a `COMMIT` before ending.  One way to do this is to write the code to perform the `GET` by `CORRELID` with a wait interval.  If the wait interval expires, the application would get a return code of 2033 and then issue a `COMMIT` before closing the thread.  If the reply message is legitimately late for whatever reason, the `COMMIT` will have no effect.  But if the message arrived and had been backed out and requeued, the `COMMIT` will cause it to stay in the Backout Queue.

One way to see exactly what is going on is to run a trace against the queue in question.  You can use the built-in trace function - strmqtrc - which has a few more options [in V7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa16100_.htm) than does [the V6 version](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.amqzag.doc/fa16100_.htm).  However if you want very fine grained control you can use the trace exit in [SupportPac MA0W](http://bit.ly/SupportPacMA01).  With MA0W you can see exactly what API calls are made by the program and those made on its behalf.

**[EDIT]** Updating the response with some info from the PMR:

The following is from the WMQ V7 Infocenter:

> MessageConsumers are single threaded below the Session level, and
>   any requeuing of poison messages
>   takes place within the current unit of
>   work. This does not affect the
>   operation of the application, however
>   when poison messages are requeued
>   under a transacted or
>   Client_acknowledge Session, the
>   requeue action itself will not be
>   committed until the current unit of
>   work is committed by the application
>   code or, if appropriate, the
>   application container code."
>
> Hence, if it is important for the customer to have poison messages
>   committed immediately after they are
>   backed out, it is recommended they
>   either make use of the Application
>   Server Facilities
>   (ConnectionConsumer) which can commit
>   the message immediately, or
>   another mechanism to move poison
>   messages from the queue.

Here is the link to this information in the [V6](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj25590_.htm) and [V7](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm35205_.htm) Information Centers.  Since you are using the V6 client so you would want to refer to the V6 Infocenter.  *Note that with the V6 client, there is no mention in the Infocenter of ASF being able to commit the poison message immediately, even when using a ConnectionConsumer*.  The way I read it, this means you probably will need to upgrade to the V7 client to get the behavior you are looking for.  Will be interested to see if the PMR results in a similar recommendation.

Comment: @T.Rob           : We running this inside a weblogic app server under a XA transaction & MDB's onMessage() method. if there is any exception encountered in the onMessage(), it simply throws a runtime exception and the container starts rolling back. Our assumption was that this would cause the backout count to increase and once BOTHRESDHOLD is reached, the message would be automatically moved to a BACKOUT queue as we have set up. While I can follow your reasoning I am not able to understand what should I do in my code or any settings to instruct MQ to commit the poison message on the backoutQ.

Comment: @SCS075 the big question is whether there is another message behind it to push out the poison message.  If not, then add one and try again.  If so and it still misbehaves, then it's time for the trace.  Tracing will tell you if the WLS code has a bug that prevents the message from getting committed onto the BOQ - or in fact if the scenario I'm describing is actually the cause of the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @T.Rob: We pushed few messages once we started seeing this behavior in (another) test run. That didn't help much. Now I am working with the MQ Admin to have the Trace set up. A quick question, is it easy to read trace file or do we need a MQ expert?

Comment: You will need to format the trace files from strmqtrc and then can read them fairly easily.  The MA0W trace is a lot easier to read though since you can control what gets traced at a very fine grained level and everything is human-readable.  If you are comfortable with exits, use that one.  Otherwise, use strmqtrc and dspmqtrc.

Comment: Alright. I got the hang of the issue but unable to find a solution. This is because WLS server will not issue a XA_COMMIT on a backout Q (http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=49417). But what do I have to do from the code to make the Backout queue committed? I have thrown an exception, the transaction is already being rolled back, can't issue a commit, right? A Good msg is being picked by a different thread(MDB/onMsg()). What do I do then

Comment: I don't know that there's anything you can do in your code because your code isn't called by an MDB until there's a message in the buffer.  But then, I've never seen a case where there was not enough traffic in the queue to push the poison message to the BOQ and eventually call a COMMIT on it.  If adding more good messages until the thread holding the poison message gets another one doesn't work then I believe it's PMR time.

Comment: Opened one last night, will update once we get a to resolution

Comment: If you want to send the PMR number to t.rob.wyatt at us.ibm.com I will try to steer it to a colleague on the dev team for review.

Comment: I sent it to you. Just one thing I want to reiterate.The poison message i being followed with other good messages in the input Q. But that does not solve the issue. My understanding is since this is MDB, the next message in the Q is being processed by another thread. Does that sound right for why sending a good message to the input Q not solving the issue?

Comment: It sounds like there are several threads in the MDB and the good message is going to one of the other threads.  The only way to get the message to commit is for the thread that owns it to issue the commit call - that may require enough good messages in the queue for load balancing to eventually deliver one to the thread owning the poison message.  Alternatively, a V7 client may simply commit the poison message immediately, based on the documentation quoted above.